# What is the equation for a line in a family ruling a rectangle, given the rectangle's dimensions and a point on the line inside the rectangle?

Tags: geometry, analytic-geometry, surfaces, rectangles, quadrics

I have questions about the following ruling of rectangle $ABCD$ with top and bottom sides, $AB$ and $DC$, being collinear with $y=1$ and $y=−1$, respectively, and the midpoint of each lies on $x=0$. The ruling is defined as the sweep of a line through the rectangle as it follows this path: given a line collinear with side $AB$, rotate counterclockwise around vertex $B$ until it intersects with the opposite vertex $D$ (i.e., is collinear with diagonal $BD$), then rotate it clockwise around vertex $D$ until it is collinear with side $DC$.

There are an infinite number of families of lines that fit these criteria, one family per rectangle with a unique ratio of adjacent side lengths; for all families, it follows that: a) every point inside the rectangle lies on exactly one of the lines, so no two lines intersect, b) every line that is not a side of ABCD has a positive slope, and c) every line has a unique intercept.

I'm trying to find a general equation for lines in such a family, which takes as variables the ratio of one side of the rectangle to its adjacent side (to identify the family) and the xy coordinates of a point inside the rectangle, and returns the slope of the line in that family through the given point.

I suspect what I'm describing is equivalent to a rectangle cut out of the side of a single-sheet hyperboloid or some other quadric, but even so, I don't know how to go from the equation for the hyperboloid to the equation I want, other than the diagonal of the rectangle would be an asymptote of the hyperbola.

Am I right that this equation must exist, and, if so, what is it or how can I find it? Finally, is the equation associated with a particular quadric or other surface?

Comment: Can't you pose this question in three or fewer sentences?

Comment: Hm. With liberal use of semicolons, I could describe the rectangle and the sweep of the line through it in a single sentence. The description of the equation I'm seeking could be a sentence. The hypothesized relationship to a quadric could be a sentence. I can condense the three questions to two. Minimum of five sentences, only slightly shorter, probably sacrificing clarity. But I'll see what I can do.

Comment: @david-g-stork: 1 for the rectangle + 1 for the ruling + 1 for its properties that allow it to be described by a general equation + 1 for the equation parameters + 1 for the possible relationship with a quadric + 2 for questions = 7. But it is shorter!

Comment: So ... Considering an axis-aligned rectangle $\square ABCD$ with, say, $A=(-r,-1)$, $B=(r,-1)$, $C=(r,1)$, $D=(-r,1)$, and a point $P=(p,q)\in \square ABCD$, you seek a function $f(p,q,r)$ that returns the equation of line $\overleftrightarrow{PB}$ for $P\in\triangle BCD$ and the equation of line $\overleftrightarrow{PD}$ for $P\in\triangle DAB$. ... Is this close?

Comment: @Blue: This is exactly it, except if P is unique, then you have either PD or PB, not both.

Comment: @virtuolie: *"This is exactly it*" ... Actually, I goofed in orienting the rectangle, since I overlooked that you specifically want *positive* slopes. So, instead, we should take, say, $A=(-r,1)$ and go clockwise from there. ... The reference to the triangles is to help me wrap my mind around which sub-family of lines is relevant to a particular $P$. (I agree that we should get *either* $PD$ *or* $PB$ ... with the exception that we do get "both" when $P$ is on diagonal $\overline{BD}$ itself.) In any case, I've shown that the question *can indeed* be posed in three-or-fewer sentences. ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a re-statement of my re-statement of the problem (approved by OP in a comment, but with an orientation fix and an explicit vertical dimension for sanity-checking purposes):

[image]

> Consider an axis-aligned, clockwise-oriented rectangle $\square ABCD$ with
> $$A=(−r,s) \qquad B=(r,s) \qquad C=(r,-s) \qquad D=(−r,-s)$$
> and consider a point $P=(p,q)\in \square ABCD$. We seek a function $f(p,q,r,s)$
> such that
> $$f(p,q,r,s) = \begin{cases} \text{equation of $\overleftrightarrow{PB}$}, & P\in\triangle ABD\\[4pt]
> \text{equation of $\overleftrightarrow{PD}$}, & P\in\triangle CDB \end{cases} \tag{1}$$

The line equations are easy enough to generate:

$$\begin{align}
\overleftrightarrow{PB}:&\quad (s-q) x - (r-p) y = ps - qr \\
\overleftrightarrow{PD}:&\quad (s+q) x - (r+p) y = ps - qr
\end{align} \tag{2}$$

The cases are determined by whether $P$ lies above or below the diagonal $\overline{BD}$. The equation of that diagonal is $sx-ry=0$, so the condition corresponds to whether $(x,y)\to(p,q)$ makes $sx-ry$ *negative* (for "above") or *positive* (for "below"). With an explicit *zero* case, we have

$$f(p,q,r,s) = \begin{cases} 
(s-q) x - (r-p) y = ps - qr, & ps < qr \\[4pt]
sx - ry = 0, & ps = qr \\[4pt]
(s+q) x - (r+p) y = ps - qr, & ps > qr \end{cases} \tag{3}$$

Defining $\lambda := \operatorname{sgn}(ps-qr)$, we can unify the above into

> $$f(p,q,r,s) \quad\to\quad (s+\lambda q) x - (r+\lambda p) y = ps - qr \tag{$\star$}$$

or this symmetric-looking alternative

> $$f(p,q,r,s) \quad\to\quad (s+\lambda q) (x-p) = (r+\lambda p) (y-q) \tag{$\star\star$}$$

Substituting $s=1$ for OP's particular needs is left as an exercise to the reader. :)

Here's the function in action (with $P$ not constrained to lie within the rectangle):

[image]

Comment: Excellent! I have advanced to a more complicated, 3D version of this question, and will be posting soon. Hope you will take a look.